# Rxjs Map Array in Json Document to new Array type

Tags: javascript, mapping, angular6, rxjs6

I am retrieving a document from PouchDB in an Angular Service.  The document is retrieved in the following format:

```
{
"_id":"segments",
"_rev":"1-4f0ed65cde23fe724db13bea1ae3bb13",
"segments":[
    { "name":"Aerospace" },
    { "name":"Auto repair" },
    { "name":"Commercial" },
    { "name":"Education" },
    { "name":"Energy" },
    { "name":"Farm/ranch" },
    { "name":"Furniture" },
    { "name":"Heavy Equipment" },
    { "name":"Hobbyist" },
    { "name":"Infrastructure" },
    { "name":"Luxury/Leisure" },
    { "name":"Military" },
    { "name":"MUP" },
    { "name":"Processing" },
    { "name":"Rail" },
    { "name":"Transportation" }
]}
```

And I want to map that to a new Array that would look like:

```
[
  { value: "Aerospace", viewValue: "Aerospace" },
  { value: "Auto Repair", viewValue: "Auto Repair" },
  { value: "Commercial", viewValue: "Commercial" }
  ...
 ]
```

To accomplish this, I have tried this code in my Service:

```
getSegments(): Observable<any[]> {
  return from(this.database.get('segments'))
  .pipe(
    map((results) => results.segments)
  );
}
```

And I transform the array in my Component like this:

```
segments: SegmentsLookup[] = [];
...
this.lookupDbService.getSegments()
  .subscribe(data => {
    data.forEach(element => {
      this.segments.push({value: element.name, viewValue: element.name});
  });
});
```

This works but I know there is a way to map this properly back in the Service code.  Also, when done this way, the compiler complains about the "results.*segments*" stating "Property "segments" does not exist on type '{}'.

How do I map the data retrieved to the Array that I need in the Service's "getSegments" method?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can do the transformation is 2 steps:

- pipe/map to extract the segments
- array/map to convert to the final data type

Please see an example here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ikb2eg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

```
let transformedData = observableData.pipe(
  map(data => {
    console.log(data, data.segments.length);
    return data.segments.map(element => {
      return { value: element["name"], viewValue: element["name"] };
    });
  })
);

transformedData.subscribe(data => {
  this.mylist = data;
});
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the RxJS operator `flatMap`, which is a alias of [mergeMap](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/mergeMap).

The official documentation describes `flatMap` as follows:

> Projects each element of an observable sequence to an observable
>   sequence and merges the resulting observable sequences or Promises or
>   array/iterable into one observable sequence.

We can use `flatMap` and then the RxJS operator `map` like this:

- `flatMap` to extract the segments
- `map` to convert to the final data type

```js
const transformedData = observableData.pipe(
  flatMap(data => data.segments),
  map(segment => ({
    value: segment['name'],
    viewValue: segment['name'],
  })),
)

transformedData.subscribe(data => {
  this.mylist = data;
});
```

**Detailed explanation of how this works:**

This [article](https://medium.com/@w.dave.w/becoming-more-reactive-with-rxjs-flatmap-and-switchmap-ccd3fb7b67fa) nicely explains how `flatMap` works and implements a version of `flatMap`, which works with arrays rather than RxJS observables, as follows:

```js
function flatMap (arr, fn) {
  return arr.reduce((flatArr, subArray) => flatArr.concat(fn(subArray)), [])
}
```

If we use this with the result of your database query we'll see we extract the segments.

```js
const data = {
"_id": "segments",
"_rev": "1-4f0ed65cde23fe724db13bea1ae3bb13",
"segments": [
  { "name": "Aerospace" },
  { "name": "Auto repair" },
  // ...
]};

const segments = flatMap([data], x => x.segments);

console.log(segments);

// > [
// >  { "name": "Aerospace" },
// >  { "name": "Auto repair" },
// >  ...
// > ]
```

The RxJS `flatMap` operator returns an observable stream of segments, rather than an array of segments.

Comment: Will you need a `combineAll()` to convert it back to an array?

Answer (score 2):

You can extend the map function and remove it from the component as follows :

```
map(result => {
        result = result.segments;
        let data = [];
        result.forEach(element => {
            data.push({value: element.name, viewValue: element.name});
        });
        return data;
 });
```