# Is it possible to get object from c# server into an Typescript object with more fields?

Tags: c#, asp.net, angular, typescript, angular8

I have a C# ASP.NET server that returns Animals objects list to my angular 8 project,
Is it possible to set more fields in the Animal class on the client side- angular?

Hope you understand me,
Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Yes, it possible

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example (assume everything is working at this point):

```
this.http.get<Animal[]>(....).pipe(
  flatMap(items => items),
  map(item => ...your mapping function here...)
);
```

See also more examples from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52098315/rxjs-map-array-in-json-document-to-new-array-type)